# По какой причине тут ставится двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

"Кино и телевидение оказали огромное воздействие на театр: монументальные декорации окончательно уступили место легким зачастую условным,меняющимся по ходу действия изменилась манера игры актеров".

Answer (score 1):

Да здесь ещё знаков не хватает. По-моему, предложение должно выглядеть так: **"Кино и телевидение оказали огромное воздействие на театр: монументальные декорации окончательно уступили место легким, зачастую условным,меняющимся по ходу действия, изменилась манера игры актеров".**

Comment: А это задание тоже из ЕГЭ, и задающему абсолютно все равно, какие знаки. Я когда на первый "ЕГЭшный" вопрос ответила, поняла, что это у нас, на ДАльнем Востоке,  ЕГЭ закончился. А этот вопрос(и второй вопрос ГУли), скорее всего, "пришел" прямо с экзамена. Поэтому ответила позже. Конечно, на такие вопросы мы не должны отвечать. но знаю, что многие после экзамена пытаются проверить, правильно ли они выполнили.

Answer (score 0):

Вторая часть предложения раскрывает, поясняет смысл первой.